# d3.js - Treemap where parent's value is greater than sum of its children

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

I am trying to use d3.js to display a treemap where a parent's value may be greater than the sum of its children. For example, say I am visualizing lines of code in a namespace hierarchy. Namespace B and C are children of A and are 1 line each. Namespace A is 3 lines - 1 line for B and C and 1 line for itself. Thus B and C alone do not dictate the size of A.

I want to display this property on the treemap. In particular, the parent should be a rectangle on top of the children rectangles whose size is correctly proportional. If the parent does not add any additional size, the parent should still be displayed but at minimal size (maybe a tiny rectangle spanning the top of the children, just to indicate the parent name).

Currently the children value nodes are just propagated up the hierarchy disregarding the actual size of non-leaf nodes.

I would like a solution in d3.js, because that is the library I am using in the rest of the code, but I am open to another framework if it solves the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [pull request #574](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/574) which allows internal hierarchy nodes to have value.

Otherwise, you could add invisible dummy nodes to your data that contain the extra value associated with internal nodes but not accounted for by their children. When you render the treemap, you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) those nodes to prevent them from being displayed (even though they're part of the layout). Or you could set their style to display: none.

Comment: I messed around with the pull request but wasn't getting the behavior I was expecting, so I went the dummy node route and it worked well! I put together a little example here devforrest.com/examples/treemap/treemap.php. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks for your example! It saved me from having to reimplement the same thing :)