# d3.js Respect weights for each treemap node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently working on a project using a modified Zoomable Treemap (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) in d3.js but I have run into some difficulty in implementing this specific behavior that I'm looking for.

Ideally, each node in the tree would be sized according to its specified weight rather than the sum of the weights of its children. The only relevant question I could find ([d3.js - Treemap where parent's value is greater than sum of its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253740/d3-js-treemap-where-parents-value-is-greater-than-sum-of-its-children/11257008#11257008)) isn't quite what I'm looking for, though it could potentially be used to create a similar effect. However, attempting to use the filtered dummy node method to keep the parent's size constant when its children are modified results in ugly transitioning artifacts. I assume this due to the higher level being aware of the dummy node, but the lower level not being aware (as it is filtered, so it is not visible).

How might I go about implementing this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the implementation that I was using already had a function (accumulate(d)) that was responsible for this behavior. I solved this issue by rewriting it to always return the node's value directly like so:

```
function accumulate(d) {
    var result = (d._children = d.children)
            ? d.value
            : d.value;
    if(d.children){
        d.children.forEach(accumulate);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now the nodes scale independently of their children as desired.

Hopefully this saves someone else some confusion in the future.